# SQL Server: Select multiple fields and display the count of duplicates in one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have a SQL Server table with the following fields and sample data:

USERS TABLE

```
ID         Name   Address
23052-PF   Peter  Timbuktu
23052-D1   Jane   Paris
23052-D2   David  London
23050-PF   Sam    Beijing
23051-PF   Nancy  NYC
23051-D1   Carson Cali
23056-PF   Grace  LA
```

AGE TABLE

```
ID         Age
23052-PF   25
23052-D1   22
23052-D2   25
23050-PF   22
23051-PF   26
23051-D1   22
23056-PF   28
```

I need to return ID, Name, Address, Age and number of occurrences of the Age column in a separate column.

The table needs to be sorted in descending order based on the count of the age column.

The output for the sample data above needs to be as below:

```
ID         Name   Address   Age  Age(Count)
23052-PF   Peter  Timbuktu  25   3
23056-PF   Grace  LA        25   3
23051-D1   Carson Cali      25   3
23052-D1   Jane   Paris     22   2
23050-PF   Sam    Beijing   22   2
23052-D2   David  London    24   1
23051-PF   Nancy  NYC       26   1
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
select u.id, u.name, u.address, a.age, count(*) over (partition by ages) as "Age(Count)"
from users u join
     ages a
     on u.id = a.id
order by "Age(Count)" desc
```

You can also use:

```
order by 4 desc
```

although use of column numbers in `order by` is discouraged.

Comment: I knew that you could not used an aliased column in the `WHERE` clause but I did not realize that you could use an aliased column name in the `ORDER BY` clause. Now I know! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

This should get you what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE #u
(
    id          nvarchar(100),
    Name        nvarchar(100),
    Address     nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #u
SELECT N'23052-PF', N'Peter',  N'Timbuktu' UNION
SELECT N'23052-D1', N'Jane',   N'Paris'    UNION
SELECT N'23052-D2', N'David',  N'London'   UNION
SELECT N'23050-PF', N'Sam',    N' Beijing' UNION
SELECT N'23051-PF', N'Nancy',  N'NYC'      UNION
SELECT N'23051-D1', N'Carson', N'Cali'     UNION
SELECT N'23056-PF', N'Grace',  N'LA'

CREATE TABLE #a
(
    id          nvarchar(100),
    Age         int
)

INSERT INTO #a
SELECT N'23052-PF', 25 UNION
SELECT N'23052-D1', 22 UNION
SELECT N'23052-D2', 25 UNION
SELECT N'23050-PF', 22 UNION
SELECT N'23051-PF', 26 UNION
SELECT N'23051-D1', 22 UNION
SELECT N'23056-PF', 28

;WITH
cte AS
(
    SELECT
        u.id,
        u.Name,
        u.Address,
        a.Age,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Age) AS [Age(Count)]
    FROM
        #u AS u INNER JOIN #a AS a
            ON
                u.id = a.id
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    [Age(Count)] DESC
```